# Is there an easy way to dedupe a Hive table?

Tags: hive, apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

I have a set of Hive tables on Elastic Map-Reduce which have some duplicate elements.  Is there an easy way of deduping these tables?

What comes to mind is dumping to a set of pig-digestible files, firing up pig and using a DISTINCT query to regenerate the table.  That seems like quite a bit of work, though, so I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: Let's assume "elements" means rows. Are these duplicated rows exactly duplicates, or do they differ by some of the columns? By deduping the table do you mean to keep all of the columns, and not just the ones the rows are duplicated by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One query should remove duplicates:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2 , ..., ColN FROM table
```

Comment: I agree - what if the rows are not exactly duplicates and yet the columns where they differ do need to be returned? I believe other databases allow you to specify separate sets of columns for distinct and select.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to dedupe on a unique column like (customer, host, product, location), you can also join it to itself.

Useful if you get multiple entries with different time stamps or whatever.

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table
select a.* from my_table a
inner join ( select min(id) as id from my_table group by unique_column ) b on ( a.id = b.id );
```